# Uniswap Factory contract event - how to find addresses for new token pair

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, uniswap

When creating a new pair on Uniswap, Uniswap emits a PairCreated event that details which tokens are invovled. However, it sorts the token like this in the factory contract:

```
        (address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
```

I'm lost as to retrieving specific token(s) as the order changes, here's what I did by comparing the bytes:

```
token0 := vLog.Topics[1].Hex()
bA := []byte(token0)

token1 := vLog.Topics[2].Hex()
bB := []byte(token1)

if bytes.Compare(bA, bB) < 0 {
        newToken = token0
        backedToken = token1
    } else {
        newToken = token1
        backedToken = token0
    }
fmt.Println("newToken", newToken)
fmt.Println("backedToken", backedToken)
```

But it is still incorrect. What's the right way to go about this, and why does Uniswap compare the token addresses like this?

Comment: the line with the sort in the factory contract first mentions two address arguments `token0` and `token1`, but then mentions `tokenA` and `tokenB`, which I'm guessing are amounts. Could you bring in where `tokenA` and `tokenB` are coming from?

Comment: I just named it differently in my code lol but ya I've changed it

Comment: thanks, but I had meant in the first code block, which I think is from the Uniswap contract

Comment: it's from here
https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol

If you look under the createPair function

Comment: okay, I'm starting to grok this a bit more. Could you add what language/web3 library you're using, and also what information specifically from the tokens you're looking for? I can guess, but it's always better to write out in the question.

Comment: They are sorted because as a pair USDT/BAT should be the same as BAT/USDT.